# git log --full-diff, what does it do?

Tags: git

The [git-log documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) explains the parameter `--full-diff`.

In detail:

> Without this flag, git log -p ... shows commits that touch the specified paths, and diffs about the same specified paths. With this, the full diff is shown for commits that touch the specified paths; this means that "…​" limits only commits, and doesn’t limit diff for those commits.
>
> Note that this affects all diff-based output types, e.g. those produced by `--stat`, etc.

I've no idea what it tries to explain, can someone give me an example maybe.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Sure. Let's say you have a commit C that makes changes to file A and file B.

Regular `git log -p -- A` will show all commits that touch file A, and for those commits, it'll show the diffs to A.
With `--full-diff`, it'll show the same commits, but for each commit it'll show the  diff of *all* files changed in that commit. In this case, commit C's diff will show diffs for files A and B.